# C++ results with formula not matching specifying value

Tags: c++, equation

Why do the following not equal each other?

```
0.37024025
```

and

```
(sqrt(2)*M_PI/3)*(1/4)
```

I see significant divergence in my solution, but all I did was place a number with the formula behind it.

Comment: `*(1/4)` is probably not giving what you expect.

Comment: Why is that not going to end well?

Comment: @Ben Integer division.

Comment: Do you really want to multiply by zero?

Comment: oh wow, how did i miss that, thanks!

Comment: We've probably all done it.

Comment: @Ben Note that due the nature of floating point math, even if you fix the problem of integer division you may still [have problems with comparing the two expressions for equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `(sqrt(2)*M_PI/3)*(1/4)` has integer division. Namely, `(1/4)` is always going to be zero, making the entire expression zero since it's multiplied by that.

```
(sqrt(2.0)*M_PI/3.0)*(1.0/4.0);
```

Is a little bit closer to what you wanted, but when comparing doubles exactly I'd use an epsilon threshold and test if both are "close enough" to each other based on that:

```
bool cmp(double d1, double d2, double epsilon)
{
    return std::fabs(d1 - d2) < epsilon;
}
```

Comment: You've gone overboard on your corrections.  sqrt(2) works fine because the argument to the function is a double and the integer 2 will be passed in as a double.  `M_PI/3` works fine because of promotion, the numerator is a double so the denominator will be promoted to a double and double-precision division will be performed.  The only expression that doesn't work as was intended is `1/4` because they are both integers and integer division is applied resulting in 0.

Comment: @Wyck I'm aware that `M_PI` promotes the division to `double`, and that `sqrt` returns a `double`; I just like to be explicit about my intent in my code

Comment: there is more to comparing floating points than adding the epsilon. You also have to be aware that many properties that one would expect dont hold for such a comparsion, most obviously it is not safe to assume that `cmp(a,b) && cmp(a,c)` implies `cmp(b,c)`

Comment: Yeah, I think that's probably the corrective technique we all end up adopting in practice.  Appreciation of the nuances of why it works sometimes and not all the time is important though.

Comment: An absolute epsilon like this also tends to be iffy. You have to know the approximate magnitude of the values a-priori for it to make sense.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Well, I did leave it as a parameter to `cmp` so that it can be filled in arbitrarily at the call site.

Answer (score 1):

You're performing integral division with `1/4` which will result in `0`, not `0.25`. Try adding a `.0f` or `.0` suffix for float or double, respectively.